# How to capture python subprocess stdout in unittest

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to write a unit test that executes a function that writes to stdout, capture that output, and check the result. The function in question is a black box: we can't change how it is writing it's output. For purposes of this example I've simplified it quite a bit, but essentially the function generates its output using subprocess.call().

No matter what I try I can't capture the output. It is always written to the screen, and the test fails because it captures nothing. I experimented with both print() and os.system(). With print() I can capture stdout, but not with os.system() either.

It's also not specific to unittesting. I've written my test example without that with the same results.

Questions similar to this have been asked a lot, and the answers all seem to boil down to use subprocess.Popen() and communicate(), but that would require changing the black box. I'm sure there's an answer I just haven't come across, but I'm stumped.

We are using Python-2.7.

Anyway my example code is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
sys.dont_write_bytecode = True

import os
import unittest
import subprocess
from contextlib import contextmanager
from cStringIO import StringIO

# from somwhere import my_function
def my_function(arg):
    #print('my_function:', arg)
    subprocess.call(['/bin/echo', 'my_function: ', arg], shell=False)
    #os.system('echo my_function: ' + arg)

@contextmanager
def redirect_cm(new_stdout):
    old_stdout =  sys.stdout
    sys.stdout =  new_stdout
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        sys.stdout = old_stdout

class Test_something(unittest.TestCase):
   def test(self):
        fptr = StringIO()
        with redirect_cm(fptr):
            my_function("some_value")

        self.assertEqual("my_function: some_value\n", fptr.getvalue())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: This is actually pretty non-trivial dependent on how `subprocess` is implemented, and processes in general. Without OS-level hacks you can't easily take control of a process's file descriptors, say, before it `exec`s. What's the actual use case? Can you replace your "black box" function with a mock function? Or maybe use monkeypatch to temporarily change `subprocess.call`'s default arguments to, say, redirect stdout to a file.

Comment: Thanks. Our actual "my_function" is only slightly more complicated that my example; it just massages it arguments, constructs a command, and runs it. I need to test the "my_function" function, so mocking it defeats the purpose. I have considered monkeypatching subprocess.call with something that just prints the argument list, which I could then capture with the context manager above. That might even be the best approach, since that way the command string doesn't get executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two issues in the above code

1. `StringIO fptr` does not shared by the current and the spawned process, we could not get the result in current process even if the spawned process has written result to `StringIO` object
2. [Changing `sys.stdout` doesn’t affect the standard I/O streams](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.stdout) of processes executed by `os.popen()`, `os.system()` or the `exec*()` family of functions in the os module

A simple solution is

1. use `os.pipe` to share result between the two processes
2. use `os.dup2` instead of changing `sys.stdout`

A demo example as following shown

```
import sys
import os
import subprocess
from contextlib import contextmanager


@contextmanager
def redirect_stdout(new_out):
    old_stdout = os.dup(1)
    try:
        os.dup2(new_out, sys.stdout.fileno())
        yield
    finally:
        os.dup2(old_stdout, 1)


def test():
    reader, writer = os.pipe()

    with redirect_stdout(writer):
        subprocess.call(['/bin/echo', 'something happened what'], shell=False)

    print os.read(reader, 1024)


test()
```

Comment: Thanks, and thanks for the link. I'm sure I read that statement many years ago, but clearly it slipped my mind since them. What a drag it is... Anyway, I will give the approach a try. It seems pretty straightforward.

Comment: @MarkE.Hamilton How about the result, does it okay?

Comment: Jacky, I apologize for not getting back to this. I experimented with this solution, but ran into this error: 

 os.dup2(new_out.fileno(), sys.stdout.fileno())
 AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'fileno'

After researching this and not finding a good solution we decided to go the route of just mocking subprocess.call to avoid the issue. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. In my example, `writer` is already a file descriptor(an integer), no need to call `.fileno`. I have updated it

Comment: Thanks for the Christmas present. That does answer my question.